# Trying to use a Chrome Extension to fetch certain pieces of text from a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

this is my first attempt at building a Chrome extension and I'm trying to learn how by building an extension that tracks the television series I watch. The extension is supposed to, among other things, fetch metadata about the series and display this on an html page. However whenever I try to fetch the title of the series using its tag or class, etc. (determined using Chrome's Inspect Element function) I end up with "undefined". I have tried using .innerText but the same happens.

Here is the Javascript I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("subscribe").addEventListener("click",myFunction);
function myFunction() {
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subscribe: "yes"}, function(response) {
            var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
            bkg.console.log(response.confirm);
            bkg.console.log(response.aTitle); \\I wrote this to check the data I fetched, but this always gives an undefined
            document.getElementById("anTitle").innerHTML=response.aTitle;
        });
    });
}
```

});

Here is the content script I am using:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.subscribe=="yes"){
        console.log("Subscription: " + request.subscribe);
        sendResponse({
            confirm: "Request received",
            aTitle: document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerText \\this is where the title is on the webpage I tried
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log("Subscription request not received");
    }
}
```

)

Comment: Try with `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerText`

Comment: What file the first code block is in? Beware you can't directly access webpage document from a background/popup page and the restricted chrome.tabs API from a content script.

Comment: Thank you @rsanchez, `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerText` did the trick for me. Thank you very much, I've been agonising over this for a while

Comment: Thank you for your response @wOxxOm, the first code block is part of my background script